# Find all $n$ for which a polyhedron with $n$ edges exists

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

Accroding to https://plus.maths.org/content/eulers-polyhedron-formula-1 :
$2E \ge 3F$ and $2E \ge 3V$.

Using these facts and the Euler's formula $V+F-E=2$, we get that $n+2 \le \frac{4n}{3}$, but this gives $n \ge 6$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Where do you get $2F \geq 3V$? I only saw $2\color{red}{E} \geq 3V$ in the linked article.

Comment: @VTand , my mistake.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $n \geq 6$ is incorrect? What you have found is that a polyhedron must have at least $6$ edges. No conclusion has been made on whether *all* $n \geq 6$ will work.

Comment: @VTand, in the same article it is proven that for n=7, there is no polyherdon.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, those two inequalities and Euler's formula are only able to conclude that $n \geq 6$. This $n \geq 6$ is a *necessary* condition, but not a *sufficient* condition.

Comment: I agree. This was my attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any $n \geq 6$, except $n = 7$, will work.

- For even values of $n$, simply consider the pyramid with $(n/2)$-gon as its base.
- For odd values of $n$ with $n \geq 9$, start with the pyramid with $n-3$ edges. Cut a small corner around one of the base's vertices. This will generate $3$ extra edges, bringing the total number of edges to $n$. [image: A triangular pyramid with one of the corners cut]

Comment: @JeanMarie What is a simplex? [What I found on Wikipedia is different from a pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex); we're dealing only with 3D objects here. Also, the link you provided for $n = 7$ is exactly the link on the question, so that's why I didn't mention it again in my answer.

Comment: Error(s) of mine. I Delete my remarks.